# How to execute a python program in Mininet environment in multiple xterm windows simultaneously?

Tags: xterm, mininet, sdn

I have a python program (*mypro.py*) in which i want to run on all the hosts of my topology simultaneously (i.e., without going to each xtrem window and typing *python mypro.py*). Is there a way to do that on the xterm of Mininet environment by using a script?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a simple topology, h1 - s1 - h2, you could forward X11, then:

1. xterm h1 h2 (To enter into the hosts, then two windows will pop up)
2. python mypro.py

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, this is a manual way of doing it. I don't want to type the command python mypro.py in every window manually .